# Displaying posts from specific categories with the AheadWorks blog extension for Magento

Tags: magento, blogs, categories, posts

I'm using the AheadWorks blog extension for Magento, and my blog pages are working fine. But I want excerpts of my latest posts from certain categories to appear on my home page. I've successfully setup everything thus far by adding:

```
<block type="blog/blog" name="blog.latest" template="aw_blog/blog-home.phtml" />
```

to "layout.xml", by adding:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('blog.latest') ?>
```

to my home page's phtml file, and by creating "template/aw_blog/blog-home.phtml".

The problem is that I can't figure out how to limit what categories are shown. For example, you'll see in my "blog-home.phtml" file below that I'm trying to limit the posts to the "news" category. I've tried lots of solutions from other forums, but no matter what I do, I see posts from every category. Does anyone know what I need to add/take away from my code to limit the categories?

```
 <?php $posts = $this->getPosts("news"); ?>
<div id="messages_product_view">
    <?php Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true)); ?> 
    <?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?> 
</div>

<?php $numberOfPosts = 1 ?>
<?php $renderedPosts = 0 ?>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <div class="postWrapper">
        <div class="postTitle">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="postContent"><?php echo $post->getPostContent(); ?></div>
        <?php echo $this->getBookmarkHtml($post) ?>
        <div class="tags"><?php echo $this->getTagsHtml($post) ?></div>
        <div class="postDetails">
            <?php if ($this->getCommentsEnabled()): ?>
                <?php echo $post->getCommentCount(); ?> <a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>#commentBox" >Comments</a> | 
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $postCats = $post->getCats(); ?>
                                <?php echo "<h1>" . $postCats[2] . "</h1>"; ?>
            <?php if (!empty($postCats)): ?>
                <?php echo Mage::helper('blog')->__('Posted in'); ?>
                <?php foreach ($postCats as $data): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>"><?php echo $data['title']; ?></a> 
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            <?php else: ?>
            <?php endif; ?></div>
            <?php $renderedPosts ++ ?>
            <?php if ($renderedPosts = $numberOfPosts) {
                break;
            }
            ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php //$this->getPages(); ?>
```

Comment: You should email their support with a link to this post. AW are pretty great, imho. You could iterate through what's returned to see if there's a way you can locally filter the results??

Comment: Hmm, that would work, except the AW blog extension for Magento is free, and their technical support is only for paying customers. I'll try their forum, though.

Comment: Heheh, well ask anyway? And if not then buy one of their excellent extensions and ask for help. BTW, they just helped fix a confilict between one of theirs and another vendor's extensions. Problem wasn't in AW's code, but they gave us the fix. They are a great vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the quick solution:
Go to aw_blog frontend template, default might be this app/design/frontend/base/default/template/aw_blog/menu.phtml
check and replace:

```
if ($posts = $this->getRecent():
```

with

```
$currentBlogCat = Mage::getSingleton('blog/cat');

if ($posts = $this->getRecent($currentBlogCat['cat_id'])):
```

Now open up /app/code/community/AW/Blog/Block/Menu/Sidebar.php
check for the below function:

```
public function getRecent()
```

add a parameters to it:

```
 public function getRecent($currentCat=false)
```

Also, replace the following code block

```
 $collection = clone self::$_collection;               
 if (array_key_exists('categories',$data = $this->getData();) && count(explode(',', $data['categories'])) == 1) {
```

with

```
 $collection = clone self::$_collection;
 $data = $this->getData();
 if($currentCat>0)$data['categories']=$currentCat;
 # Category fix #
 if (array_key_exists('categories',$data ) && count(explode(',', $data['categories'])) == 1) {
```

Thanks!